# In my bash prompt, $(__git_ps1) is telling me something is wrong, but what?

Tags: git, bash, rebase

I've hacked my bash prompt to (in theory) tell me what git branch I'm currently in. But the output indicates that something's wrong:

```
22:07 (seesaw|REBASE-i) infwb $git branch
* master
  wkg
```

Here's the relevant code in my .bash_profile file (I'll put a larger chunck of it at the end of this question):

```
PS1="$GRAY\$(date +%H:%M)\$(__git_ps1) $GREEN\W$YELLOW \$"
```

As you can see, `$(__git_ps1)` returns `(seesaw|REBASE-i)`, even though I no longer have a seesaw branch! (I did have one, and it had a rebase problem in relation to my remote seesaw branch on github. I solved the problem, I think, and `git branch -r seesaw` successfully removed the local copy.)

I'm pretty sure that `(seesaw|REBASE-i)` is telling me that something is wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Thanks for any suggestions you might have. (chunk of .bash_profile follows)

```
-------from .bash_profile ---------

## ----- from http://en.newinstance.it/2010/05/23/git-autocompletion-and-enhanced-bash-prompt/
# Set git autocompletion and PS1 integration
if [ -f /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash ]; then
  . /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
fi

if [ -f /opt/local/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /opt/local/etc/bash_completion
fi
## ----- end 

GRAY="\[\033[1;30m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[1;33m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"

PS1="$GRAY\$(date +%H:%M)\$(__git_ps1) $GREEN\W$YELLOW \$"

----------------
```

**ADDENDUM**

@cdhowie and @manojlds, I'm impressed by your git knowledge!

`git rebase --abort` caused the info to change to `(seesaw)`. Unfortunately, I can't find `rebase-merge` (or `.git`) anywhere on my hard disk. I'm on a Mac, which does Weird Things to many FOSS tools. (I did find git itself, at /usr/local/git.) Nothing at /Library/Application Support or ~//Library/Application Support, either.

*(still later)*

It turns out that everything is all right. Somehow the `git rebase --abort` caused the seesaw branch to re-appear (I wasn't expecting that!), and the command left me with seesaw as my current branch. From there, I knew what to do.

Comment: Try `git rebase --abort`?  Looks like it thinks you're in the middle of a rebase.

Comment: @cdhowie - Then branch would show `no branch`

Comment: Not necessarily -- if he had a rebase active but managed to checkout another branch, this could conceivably happen.  (`REBASE-i` specifically refers to an interactive rebase.)  At any rate, attempting to abort the outstanding rebase is still worth a shot.

Comment: @cdhowie - you are right about that in a way. I had verified from `__git_ps1` code.

Comment: I didn't know about `__git_ps1` - thanks for asking a question about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on comments with @cdhowie, I got suspicion that `__git_ps1` is handling the git rebase scenario differently. So I looked into the source and found the following lines:

```
...
if [ -f "$g/rebase-merge/interactive" ]; then
    r="|REBASE-i"
    b="$(cat "$g/rebase-merge/head-name")"
elif [ -d "$g/rebase-merge" ]; then
    r="|REBASE-m"
    b="$(cat "$g/rebase-merge/head-name")"
...
```

So as long of the `.git/rebase-merge` exists you will be getting the "wrong" branch, even if you have moved to another branch.

`git rebase --abort` will fix it. Or delete `.git/rebase-merge`